# Finding the height of circle as a function of an angle

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm trying to find the height of a circle based on an angle, I have a diagram below.

[image: Diagram]

I can find y(theta) up to 90 degrees using simple trig, however after that I'm stumped.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: See Wikipedia for 'Sagitta'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find the distance between two horizontal lines. The further line (which is fixed) is at $y = -r$. The other line depends on the angle, and has an equation of $y = -r\cos\theta$. So we have:
$$
\Delta y = r(1 - \cos \theta)
$$

Answer (score 0):

To get the 'height' of the circle you first need to know the radius $\rho$ of the circle.
After that by definition of the trigonometric functions you have :
$$y = -\rho \cos(\theta)$$
We can see in particular 
$$ y(0)=-\rho $$
$$ y\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0 $$
$$ y(\pi)=\rho $$
$$ y\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=0 $$

Comment: Tip: Use \left( "math" \right) to get nicer parentheses.

Comment: Thank you ! It seems better indeed.